# Multiple Rescue Statements in Rails Create Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-uri, rescue

I am using open-uri and the seeds.db file.  I'm trying to run the following code using "rake db:seed --trace":

```
CSV.foreach("vendor/users1.csv", { :col_sep => ",",  :quote_char => "\"", :headers => true}) do |row|

user = User.find_by_email("sample#{i}@foobardne.com")

    if (!user.picture_url.nil?)
        begin
            file = open user.picture_url
            user.avatar = file
        rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => error
            user.avatar = nil
        rescue OpenURI::HTTPRedirect => redirect
            user.avatar = nil
        end
            user.password = user.password_confirmation = "foobar"
            user.save
    end
```

For some reason, every time I run the command, its not recognizing my second rescue statement for the redirect, and I'm getting the following output (which I shortened the end of):

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
redirection forbidden:     http://cellbio.med.harvard.edu/faculty/artavanis/images/artavanis4_2002.jpg -> https://cellbio.med.harvard.edu/faculty/artavanis/images/artavanis4_2002.jpg
```

Any idea why my code isn't catching the redirection error? Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  There is a patch to the open-uri.rb file in the ruby library.
Replace:

```
(/\A(?:http|ftp)\z/i =~ uri1.scheme && /\A(?:http|ftp)\z/i =~ uri2.scheme)
```

With:

```
(/\A(?:https?|ftp)\z/i =~ uri1.scheme && /\A(?:https?|ftp)\z/i =~ uri2.scheme)
```

in the open-uri.rb file.  The problem is with http -> https redirects.  This file was found for me in:

```
/Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the error being thrown is `OpenURI::HTTPRedirect`. Try this to check which error is getting triggered:

```
begin
  ...
rescue => e
  puts e.inspect
end
```

if the error was `StandardError` then `puts e.inspect` would return:

```
#<StandardError: StandardError>
```

Comment: When I try that, I get "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: inteRst5", any ideas?

Comment: That error means you're trying to save a model with the parameter `:inteRst5` but haven't allowed that attribute to be updated using the `attr_accessible` method in your model.